# Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to nodejs and I am getting the above-mentioned error for the below code. any help is appreciated. thankyou.

```js
PushNotifications.sendMessageToAll(announcement, (err,res) => {
   if (err){
       return res.status(500).send()
     }
  res.status(200).send()
  }
  
 sendMessageToAll: function (notification, cb) {
 payload = {....}
 admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(tokens,topic).then((res) =>{
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('/topics/NATA', payload)
      }).then((res) =>{
        console.log('sent', res)
        cb(undefined,res)
      }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log('Subscribed error',err)
        cb(err,undefined)
      })
    }
 }
```

Comment: `PushNotifications.sendMessageToAll` runs the callback without the `res` parameter

Comment: you did not include the error message. Please include the error as well as all the relevant code needed.

Comment: Could you improve the formatting of your code and/or pasting more of it? It’s hard to understand what’s going on right now because of the broken indentation and blank lines. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the property `status` doesn’t exist on `undefined` that is getting passed back on this line:

```js
cb(err,undefined)
```

The caller expects a `response` object, because it wants to use the response object to set a HTTP status code and send back a response to the browser:

```js
return res.status(500).send()
```

The solution is simple: pass `res` (short for 'response') to the error callback, instead of `undefined`:

```js
  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.log('Subscribed error', err)
    cb(err, res)
  })
```

Comment: now i am getting 2 errors `Promise rejection res is not defined` and `res.status is not a function`

Comment: Can you update your original post with properly formatted JS and the full function/scope of what you are building? `res` should be available in your promise chain because it is (supposed to be) in the function scope

Answer (score 0):

You're literally passing `undefined` to your callback `cb` which expects the second parameter to be a response object

```
.catch((err) =>{
    console.log('Subscribed error',err)
    cb(err,undefined)
  })
```

You need to make your callback be able to handle having no `res` to set the status.

Comment: now i am getting 2 errors `Promise rejection res is not defined` and `res.status is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

In the `catch` block of your promise you call the callback without the `res` input:

```
 admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(tokens,topic).then((res) =>{
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('/topics/NATA', payload)
      }).then((res) =>{
        console.log('sent', res)
        cb(undefined,res)
      }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log('Subscribed error',err)
        cb(err,undefined)  // <-- HERE the second param is res!
      })
    }
 }
```

EDIT

`res` is not defined in the `catch` block. A way could be:

```
let outerRes;
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(tokens,topic).then((res) =>{
        outerRes = admin.messaging().sendToTopic('/topics/NATA', payload)
        return outerRes;
      }).then((res) =>{
        console.log('sent', res)
        cb(undefined,res)
      }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log('Subscribed error',err)
        cb(err,outerRes)  // <-- HERE the second param is res!
      })
    }
 }
```

Comment: now i am getting 2 errors `Promise rejection res is not defined` and `res.status is not a function`

Comment: It is because res is not part of the catch input. see my edit